# What's the fastest way to find the number of elements in a sorted range?

Tags: c++, algorithm

Given a sorted list
`1, 3, 5, 6, 9....`
Is there a fast algorithm rather than `O(n)` to count the number of elements in a given range `[a, b]`, assuming that all numbers are integers?

Comment: I'm fine with either C/C++, Java or C#. Will put language tag. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `std::lower_bound` and `std::upper_bound`? Gives you more than you asked for...

Comment: find a, find b, count from a to b.  log n + log n + (the result - # of elements in [a,b]).

Comment: check out this http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/32bst/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is an O(log n) algorithm: Search for the two endpoints using [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm), the number of elements in the range is then basically the difference of the indices.

To get the exact number one needs to distinguish the cases where the endpoints of the range are in the array or not.

Comment: Do you need to take the difference plus one?  I think this is off by one.

Comment: @templatetypedef probably yes, there are several cases depending if the endpoints are actually present in the array or not.

Comment: also this is assuming that the data structure is indexable.  for example, if  the sorted data structure is a linked list or a tree, there is no index.  the OP says *sorted list*...  in which case, you have to traverse from a to b.  this is  (the result - # of elements in [a,b]) steppings, so your total would be  log n + log n + (the result - # of elements in [a,b])

Answer (score 2):

Since the list is sorted, you can find the location of a value (or, if the value is not in the list, where it should be inserted) in O(log(n)) time. You simply need to do this for both ends and subtract to get the count of elements in the range. It makes no difference whether the elements are integers; the list simply needs to be sorted.

You do need to be careful if the elements are not unique; in that case after finding a hit you may need to do a linear scan to the end of the sequence of repeated elements.

Answer (score 1):

[`lower_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) and [`upper_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound) operate on sorted containers.

First find the lower value in the range, then search from there to the end for the upper value. Implementations of the functions probably use binary search:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <list>
#include <iterator>

int main() {
    using std::list;
    using std::upper_bound;
    using std::lower_bound;
    using std::distance;

    list<int> numbers = {1, 3, 5, 6, 9};
    int a = 3;
    int b = 6;

    auto lower = lower_bound(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(),
                             a);
    auto upper = upper_bound(lower, numbers.end(),
                             b);

    int count = distance(lower, upper);

    return 0;
}
```